# python tweet parsing

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse tweets data.

My data shape is as follows:

```
59593936 3061025991 null null <d>2009-08-01 00:00:37</d> <s>&lt;a href="http://help.twitter.com/index.php?pg=kb.page&amp;id=75" rel="nofollow"&gt;txt&lt;/a&gt;</s> <t>honda just recalled 440k accords...traffic around here is gonna be light...win!!</t> ajc8587 15 24 158 -18000 0 0 <n>adrienne conner</n> <ud>2009-07-23 21:27:10</ud> <t>eastern time (us &amp; canada)</t> <l>ga</l>
22020233 3061032620 null null <d>2009-08-01 00:01:03</d> <s>&lt;a href="http://alexking.org/projects/wordpress" rel="nofollow"&gt;twitter tools&lt;/a&gt;</s> <t>new blog post: honda recalls 440k cars over airbag risk http://bit.ly/2wsma</t> madcitywi 294 290 9098 -21600 0 0 <n>madcity</n> <ud>2009-02-26 15:25:04</ud> <t>central time (us &amp; canada)</t> <l>madison, wi</l>
```

I want to get the total numbers of tweets and the numbers of keyword related tweets. I prepared the keywords in text file. In addition, I wanna get the tweet text contents, total number of tweets which contain mention(@), retweet(RT), and URL (I wanna save every URL in other file).

So, I coded like this.

```
import time
import os

total_tweet_count = 0
related_tweet_count = 0
rt_count = 0
mention_count = 0
URLs = {}

def get_keywords(filepath):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.split()

for line in open('/nas/minsu/2009_06.txt'):
    tweet = line.strip()

    total_tweet_count += 1

    with open('./related_tweets.txt', 'a') as save_file_1:
        keywords = get_keywords('./related_keywords.txt', 'r')

        if keywords in line:
            text =  line.split('<t>')[1].split('</t>')[0]

            if 'http://' in text:
                try:
                    url = text.split('http://')[1].split()[0]
                    url = 'http://' + url

                    if url not in URLs:
                        URLs[url] = []
                    URLs[url].append('\t' + text)

                    save_file_3 = open('./URLs_in_related_tweets.txt', 'a')
                    print >> save_file_3, URLs

                except:
                    pass

            if '@' in text:
                mention_count +=1

            if 'RT' in text:
                rt_count += 1

            related_tweet_count += 1

            print >> save_file_1, text

    save_file_2 = open('./info_related_tweets.txt', 'w')

print >> save_file_2, str(total_tweet_count) + '\t' + srt(related_tweet_count) + '\t' + str(mention_count) + '\t' + str(rt_count)

save_file_1.close()
save_file_2.close()
save_file_3.close()
```

The keyword set likes

```
Happy
Hello
Together
```

I think my code has many problem, but the first error is as follws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "health_related_tweets.py", line 21, in <module>
    keywords = get_keywords('./public_health_related_words.txt', 'r')
TypeError: get_keywords() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Please help me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is self explanatory in the error, you have specified two parameters in your call to get_keywords() but your implementation only has one parameter. You should change your get_keywords implementation to something like:

```
def get_keywords(filepath, mode):
   with open(filepath, mode) as f:
       for line in f:
           yield line.split()
```

Then you can use the following line without that specific error:

```
keywords = get_keywords('./related_keywords.txt', 'r')
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "health_related_tweets.py", line 23, in <module>
    if keywords in line:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not generator /// Now I got this error. plz help me out!

Comment: @MINSUPARK `get_keywords()` returns a generator, not a string, so when you call `if keywords in line:` you're getting that error because `keywords` is not a string.

Comment: @CodyHess Then how do I solve it? actually, i'm a beginner... . so i need your help!

Answer (score 0):

Now you are getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "health_related_tweets.py", line 23, in  if keywords in line: TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not generator

The reason is that `keywords = get_keywords(...)` returns a generator. Logically thinking about it, keywords should be a list of all the keywords. And for each keyword in this list, you want to check if it's in the tweet/line or not.

Sample code:

```
keywords = get_keywords('./related_keywords.txt', 'r')
has_keyword = False
for keyword in keywords:
  if keyword in line:
    has_keyword = True
    break
if has_keyword:
  # Your code here (for the case when the line has at least one keyword)
```

(The above code would be replacing `if keywords in line:`)

Comment: I got another error. (Traceback (most recent call last): File "health_related_tweets.py", line 25, in <module> for keyword in keywords: File "health_related_tweets.py", line 13, in get_keywords yield line.split().lower() AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower') I thought that I need to transform the keywords and tweets which will be parsed in lower case for parsing. So I put the ".lower" in my code. But it makes error.... . How should I fix it?